# "Impetuum perseverantia" - "Persevere in endeavours" motto for coat of arms

Tags: translation-check, motto

I would like to check translation of a motto that would read "[we] persevere in endeavours/resolve".

I consider using either ***persto*** or ***persevero***. The latter seems better to me as it resonates with Modern English "to persevere". What are the lexical differences between these two words?

I'm completely zero in Latin grammar, but as far as I understand I should use genitive/ablative case here. So I came up with the following options:

> Impetuum perseverantia
>
> Impetibus perseverantia
>
> Perseverantia in impetibus

Are these grammatically correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For a motto there are several snappier, more 'Latiny', phrases that you might consider. If you want to pursue a steadfast course — which is how I interpret your motto's purpose — you should probably indicate an  objective in some way, for which I suggest the word *propositum*. There are many first-rank classical writers who use the word, adding an adjective or verb in some form to indicate the required persistence.

Caesar, for example, uses *propositum tenere*, 'to stick to the objective' (B. Civ. III, 42 : *ubi propositum tenere non potuit*, 'when he was unable to hold to his plan'). Rather more weakly, the verb *habere* is used instead of *tenere*, meaning merely to have a goal in mind. Suetonius (de Gramm. 24) has *in proposito mansit*, 'remained on his objective', meaning that [M. Valerius Probus] did not give up.

Using the first person singular, the form of verb to use in those phrases is either *teneo*, *habeo* or *maneo*. In a jussive sense, you might use the subjunctive: *propositum teneamus* is 'let us hold to our plan/task/objective' etc.

If you want your motto to state its intention as a matter of principle, you could choose an adjective, as in *tenax ad propositum* or *tenax in proposito*, 'tenacious in endeavour ' (the plural is *tenaces*). This is what I should prefer for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for "endeavor" is *inceptum*, which literally means "something begun". (*Impetus* isn't quite right here -- it means "attack, assault" rather than "endeavor".) There are a few attested Latin phrases using this word, all meaning more or less "persevere in what one has begun":

- *haerere in incepto* (Vergil, *Aeneid* 2.654)
- *inceptum peragere* (*ibid.* 4.452)
- *inceptum perficere* (Sallust, *Jugurtha* 11)
- *permanere in incepto* (Cicero, *Epistulae ad Familiares* 5.14)

These are all more or less synonymous, though with some nuances of meaning. I've cited them with infinitives, but you may want first-person singular or some other verb forms (if so we can help you find the correct form). Also, the word order is fluid so you can just as well say *in incepto haerere, peragere inceptum*, etc.